# Let $X, Y$ be independent RVs given the variances and no means what is correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Z=2X+Y$?

Tags: self-study, correlation, variance, covariance

Let $X, Y$ be independent RV given the variance and no means what is correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Z=2X+Y$?

Given $var(X)=3, var(Y)=4$ and $\mathbf{E}[X]$ and $\mathbf{E}[Y]$ are not known, let $Z=2X+Y$. What is the correlation coefficient?

$Var(2X + Y) = Var(Z) = 2^2\times Var(X) + Var(Y) = 12 + 4 = 16$

I don't know where to go from here

Comment: Calculate $cov(X,Z)$, then normalise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition:
\begin{equation}
Corr(X,Z)=\frac{Cov(X,Z)}{\sqrt{Var(X)}\sqrt{Var(Z)}}
\end{equation}
You know that $Var(X)=3$ and $Var(Y)=4$. Since Z is a linear affin transformation of $X$ and $X$ and $Y$are independent, you get:
\begin{align}
Var(Z)&=Var(2X+Y)=4Var(X)+Var(Y)=12+4=16
\end{align}
You can calculate the covariance between X and Z as:
\begin{align}
Cov(X,Z)=Cov(X,2X+Y)=2Cov(X,X)+Cov(X,Y)=2Var(X)=2\cdot3=6
\end{align}
The result is:
\begin{align}
Corr(X,Z)=\frac{6}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{16}}
\end{align}